# Piping IP address from dig to whois

Tags: bash, pipe, whois, dig

I want to get the IP address of a domain name with `dig` and then perform a `whois` lookup on that IP address.

I tried this:

```
dig domain.dk +short | whois
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See if you can provide the output from your attempt; in what way did it not work for you? Then phrase your question as, well, a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use output of bash command (with pipe) as a parameter for another command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635705/use-output-of-bash-command-with-pipe-as-a-parameter-for-another-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is just to write:

```
whois $(dig example.com +short)
```

Note that multiple IP addresses might be returned by `dig` so `whois` might sometimes complain that it doesn't know which whois server to use. In that case you might want to choose which of the IP addresses you look up. You could pick the first one with:

```
whois $(dig example.com +short | head -n1)
```

A more readable way that's also slightly closer to your original question is the following (pointed out by @tripleee in the comments):

```
dig +short example.com | xargs whois
```

(and `dig +short example.com | head -n1 | xargs whois` to look up just the first IP address returned by `dig`)

Comment: Or `dig +short example.com | xargs whois`