# why isnt it piping to the cd command?

Tags: linux, bash

I read that if you use the | command then it pipes the output of the first command to the input of the second,then why is it working?

Thank you!

```
find -size 1033c | cd
```

Comment: because `cd` ignores stdin

Comment: This would only work if the second command would read from stdin, which is not the case in this case, and if the second command would not be executed in a separate environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use output of bash command (with pipe) as a parameter for another command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635705/use-output-of-bash-command-with-pipe-as-a-parameter-for-another-command)

Comment: if you want to operate on all the files retirieved by 'find' then use `find -size 1033c -exec cd {} \;`

Comment: @Krishnom - No that won't work.  That will change the directory in a child process ... which will immediately exit!

Comment: Standard input and arguments are two very different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cd` command doesn't read standard input, so anything that you pipe to it will be ignored.

The closest to what your command is (literally) trying to do will be this:

```
cd `find -size 1033c`
```

... except that you are liable to 'cd' to a file (which will fail!) or not find a directory with that size ... leading to you (silently) cd-ing to the user's home directory.

And also your `find` command is missing a directory to search!

---

Based on your comments, you are trying to `cd` to the directory *containing* a file with a given size.  If we can assume that there will only ever be one such file, then the following should work:

```
FILE=`find . -size 1033c -type f` 
cd `dirname $FILE`
```

If there could be more than one match, then you need to do something like this ... which should cd to the directory with the first matching file.

```
FILE=`find . -size 1033c -type f -print -quit` 
cd `dirname $FILE`
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to find a file dir?